# Why does Julia throw a premature end of input error when i write and if statement?

Tags: julia

This is my code:

```
using Printf
using Statistics

age = 12
if age < 10
    println("$age")
```

This is the error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: syntax: incomplete: premature end of input
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at D:\julia\trial.jl:5
 [2] include(::Module, ::String) at .\Base.jl:377
 [3] exec_options(::Base.JLOptions) at .\client.jl:288
 [4] _start() at .\client.jl:484
in expression starting at D:\julia\trial.jl:5
```

It works well if I remove the if statement and just print the value of age.

Comment: If you don't want to use end, you could also use `age < 10 && println("$age")` (without if). This syntax may seem strange first, but it is often used in Julia code. And also the similar one with `left || right` that executes `right` only if `left` is false.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Julia terminates its blocks with an `end` keyword (and does not rely on whitespace to define its blocks).

```
age = 12
if age < 10
    println("$age")
end
```